# How to get pattern name in spacy span object?

Tags: nlp, spacy

I'm trying to find emoji in the text, while doing this I separated the emoji to 2 categories (Positive and negative), I can able to get the emoji but I need to get the pattern name also.

[image]

```
import spacy 
from spacy.matcher import Matcher 

nlp = en_core_web_md.load()
matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab)

pos_emoji = ["", "", ""]
neg_emoji = ["", "", ""]


pos_patterns = [[{"ORTH": emoji}] for emoji in pos_emoji]
neg_patterns = [[{"ORTH": emoji}] for emoji in neg_emoji]

matcher.add("posEmoji", pos_patterns)
matcher.add("negEmoji", neg_patterns)


doc = nlp(" I love Zara ")
for mid, start, end in matcher(doc):
    print(start, end, doc[start:end])
    print(doc[start:end].name_)  # Here I need to get the pattern name
```

Please help me to find the pattern name, Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

`mid` ("match id") in `mid, start, end` is the hash value of the matched pattern name. Use `nlp.vocab.strings[mid]` to look up the corresponding string.

See: https://spacy.io/usage/rule-based-matching#adding-patterns